# Launching Frama-c neon with jessie

Tags: frama-c, why3

I have installed frama-c and why3 but when i try to launch frama-c I get an error with jessie3.

```
frama-c -verbose 2
[kernel] warning: cannot load plug-in `Jessie3' (incompatible with Neon-20140301).
The exact failure is: error loading shared library:
/usr/local/lib/framac/plugins/Jessie3.cmxs: undefined symbol: camlGzip
```

I have not found any information about camlGzip so it can be an error in any config file (it can be camlzip) but i havent foud where it is declared.

Edit: I have tried to modifie the camlGzip in camlzip in Jessie3.cmxs but it create a segmentation fault when i launch frama-c

My frama-c and Why3 versions :

```
frama-c -version
Version: Neon-20140301

why3 --version
Why3 platform, version 0.85 (build date: Wed Oct 29 10:42:47 CET 2014)
```

I work on a Mint17 virtual machine and had no error in the ./configure and make of each program

I hope somebody already had this problem and can help me

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem and kind of fixed it.
You have to install Why-2.34 to have jessie installed to your frama-c lib. Download from this link:https://opam.ocaml.org/packages/why/why.2.34/

I had some trouble compile it as I have to remove coq to have it successfully compiled. BTW anyone know how should I report the coq compile error please help.

Also if you have Why3.85, I suggest you downgrade to 3.83, as it seems to be the only version that is recognized by Why.2.34.

Cheers.